# Excel - hidden field to preview contents of cell

Tags: excel

Do you know why my excel doesn't show me this field:

[excel interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzIb7.png)

I can't see or modify the content of any cell

Comment: View Tab, Check Formula Bar

Answer (score 1):

click on **Excel Options** and move to the **Advanced tab**. Scroll to the Display section.

**check** the box labeled **Show Formula Bar** and **click OK:**

Option>Advance>FormulaBar>Ok